# custom data replication in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I'm wondering how I can go about implementing a custom data replication strategy where I would have complete control over how each record gets replicated (can it be done by overriding the Partitioner and/or ReplicatePlacementStrategy?).

I want to be able to replicate only a select few records while leaving the rest alone. 
So, basically I want to say: "Replicate this record through ALL nodes" or "Replicate that record through only two nodes" or "Don't replicate the records at all!"

If such a thing is not possible, is the easiest thing then simply using the ONE/ALL/QUORUM/etc consistency levels when calling writes in-code?

Obviously, I'm new to Cassandra and haven't fully wrapped my head around it. Any clarification would be great!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you have a few specific keys that you know in advance will be hotspots for reads, or is there some other reason?

Comment: That is the precise reason why I want to do this. I intend to track the hotspots and replicate accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetworkTopologyStrategy lets you control this on a per-keyspace basis.  If you really need it per-key, you'd need to override the calculateNaturalEndpoints method in a custom Strategy.

Comment: as per your answer, is it possible to replicate a key to specific DataCenter/Rack/Node?